# No "sqrtf" in math.h

Tags: eclipse, posix, upgrade, eclipse-cdt, glibc

I am working under Ubuntu 11.04 and now engaged in a project whose source code uses routines like "sqrtf" or "lgamma", which are complained by my IDE, claiming that they cannot be found in "math.h". A senior member told me I need **POSIX.1-2001**. I used `ldd --version` to check my glibc's version and it gave `ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.13-0ubuntu13) 2.13`. I guessed the embedded version of glibc is simplified so I decided to make it upgraded to the full glibc-2.14. But after some search in aptitude I found that I have to do a manual installation. Getting frustrated all the way, I realize maybe the God is warning me off the wrong path. So...can anyone give some hints for me? Thank you~

Comment: I wrote `cout<<sqrtf(3)<<endl;` in my tentative project. The compiler ran normally, despite of Eclipse's complaint ("**Function 'sqrtf' could not be resolved**" and "**Invalid overload of 'endl'**"). So it may be ascribed to some improper settings in Eclipse.

Comment: Could you write a small testcase? It seems that you are also writing it in c++ ?

Comment: `#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main() { cout<<sqrtf(3)<<endl; return 0;}` That is what I wrote. Someone posted his case [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=350343), but it remains the same even after I rebuilt the index. It seems a bug of codan of CDT rather than my version issue of glibc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment pointed out, it was a bug of CDT.

Comment: would you care to link to the bug report and/or resolution? I have the same problem.

Comment: Yes... Please... what's the solution, I have the same problem.

Comment: @krico: Check your indexer settings. See this answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095295/why-cant-codan-find-size-t/10095683#10095683

Comment: can you tell exactly what you did? I have my settings as recommended in that answer, but still float math functions (atanf for example) are not recognized...:-(

Comment: To above users and @Christoph: as I recall, I didn't do anything for it and simply switched to another IDE because I thought it was a bug of CDT which was beyond my reach.

Answer (score 1):

Is the linker called with argument -lm?

Comment: My tentative program as above runs normally after compiled, ignoring Eclipse's complaint, so it may be a bug of Eclipse CDT.